# Output from loops

Tags: r, loops, csv

I wish to write the output from each loop iteration to a separate `.csv` file **or** add each loop as a new row in a separate object, which can them be output as a `.csv`, sequentially.

I've tried using `write.csv` but I am unsure how to apply it in the loop whereby a new file is created for each `i`.

```
for (i in seq(1,1128,12)){
  Array <- ncvar_get(temp_cont, varid = "TREFHT", start = c(1,1,1,i), count= c(144,96,60,12))
  myArray <- array(Array, dim =c(144, 96, 60, 12))
  Annual <- apply(myArray, c(1,2,3), mean)    
  myArray2 <- array(Annual, dim = c(144,96,60))
  Annuallat <- apply(myArray2, c(2,3), mean)  
  myArray3 <- array(Annuallat, dim = c(96,60))
  AnnualGLobal <- apply(myArray3, 2,mean)    
  AnnualGlobalc <- AnnualGLobal - 273.15  
  write.csv(AnnualGlobalc, file = "year[i].csv")   
}
```

Comment: Try with `file = sprintf("year%d.csv", i)`

Comment: I used the solution you provided and I thought I had marked the question as answered but obviously I hadn't, which was a mistake. Given that I thought I had marked the question as answered and the problem was solved, I had no need to return to the question. Please refrain from such smart comments in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would give you an example / start:

```
write.csv(AnnualGlobalc, file = paste0(i,".csv"))
```

You can use `paste()` or `paste0()` to generate file name associated with loop index `i` on the fly.

---

Note I did not use `paste0(year[i],".csv")`, for two concerns:

- I did not see variable `year` predefined;
- You iterate `i` through `seq(1,1128,12)`, which I sort of doubt whether `year[i]` is reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

define a list to loop through... I then would write a function that does what i want... use the function within a call to lapply()  ...